# Eclipse Scount multiple projects

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-scout

I am new eclipse scout. However I do have some experience in EclipseRCP.
I have created an application in eclipse rcp, in which it has  four modules which are four plugin projects.
Also I am using hibernate in backend  for database communication.Database is Mysql.
Below are my questions.

1. In eclipse can I create the same modules as my eclipse rcp application. I have seen 
   only one eclipse project created in different examples. So in mycase, I have four plugin projects. Do I need
   to make all these four plugin projects into one scount application?
2. Can I reuse the hibernate code which I have written in Scout application?

Answer (score 0):

1/ With the Mars version (and before) of Eclipse Scout, an Eclipse Scout Application is very similar to an Eclipse RCP Application. It runs on top of Equinox. You will be able to manage your plugins project the same way. When you create a new project, the IDE prepares some plugins, but you can have more...

2/ Nothing against reusing your Hibernate code in your Scout Application. But you might know that integrating Hibernate in the OSGi world is not so easy and requires some work.